# Importing class and using its methods accross files

Tags: methods, lua, metatable

Im trying to save myself some headache in a project im working on by splitting it up in files but I cannot seem to be able to cross call functions. (inside file_a, call a function in file_b which calls a function in file_a)

Is this just not possible or am i doing it wrong?

file_a:

```
local imported = require("fileb")
m = imported:new(BC)
m.print_message("hi")
```

file_b:

```
class_b = {
    BC = {}
}

function class_b:print_message(message)
    print(message)
end

function class_b:new (BC)
    local AB = {} 
    AB = BC or {}
    AB._index = class_b
    setmetatable(AB, self)
    return AB
end
return class_b
```

When i run this i get: attempt to call nil value (field 'print_message')

My project is much larger and complex at the moment but i extracted the logic i am working with right now to show what im trying to do to be able to cross call the functions.

Comment: This has nothing to do with files and Lua doesn't have classes. `m` does get to be a new table `{}` with the metatable set to `class_b`. But, what part of that means it should have a `print_message` function? Nothing gives `m` a `print_message` function, since it's not in the table `m` itself and there's no `__index` either.

Comment: How could i go about being able to cross use functions? Right now pretty much im trying to have class_b add itself to BC which is passed as an argument to new()

Comment: Lua doesn't look in the metatable the way you're thinking - it looks in `__index` in the metatable. So if you want it to find functions in `class_b` then you set the metatable to some table whose `__index` is `class_b`

Comment: I edited how i've got it right now. Its still not working tho, could you elaborate?

Comment: Tell me: What is the __index of AB's metatable?

Comment: AB._index = class_b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248455/discussion-between-jmelger-and-user253751).

Comment: this is a trivial error that could be avoided by carefully reading any online example on basic oop in Lua. please read the Lua manual and make sure you understand what __index does as you obviously don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `m["print_message"]` which is a nil value. Calling nil values is not allowed as it doesn't make any sense to call a nil value.

If you index a field that does not exist in a table, Lua will check wether the table has a metatable and if that metatable has a field `__index`.

While that field exists in `m` it does not exist in its metatable `class_b`.

`class_b.__index` must refer to `class_b` to make this work.